# node js: request js multipart 2nd level file and JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, requestjs

I'm trying to turn this CURL call into request.js

```
curl -i -X POST "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json" \
            -F 'oauth_token=***' \
            -F 'track[asset_data]=@music.wav' \
            -F 'track[title]=Track title' \
            -F 'track[sharing]=public'
```

The interesting bit is that the file attachment ('asset_data') is on the 2nd level of the formData object.

THIS is not working:

```
var formData = {
  oauth_token: '***',
  track: {
    asset_data: fs.createReadStream('music.wav'),
    title: 'Track title',
    sharing: 'public'
  }

}
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}...
```

I know it's because [the docs](https://github.com/request/request) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153534/how-to-send-an-object-in-multipart-formdata-using-request-in-node-js) say I have to embed the `track` inside of `JSON.stringify(track)`

but when I do that and the POST executes it comes back with `"buffer":[],"length":0`, I get the sense that it didn't wait for the file to stream before it stringify-ed it.

here's all the code in one place:

```
function postToSoundcloud(){
    var track = {'sharing': 'public',
                 'title': TRACK_NAME,
                 'asset_data': fs.createReadStream('music.wav')
                }
    var formData = {
        oauth_token: '***',
        track: JSON.stringify(track)
    };
    var req = request.post({url:'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json', 'formData': formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    }); 
}
```

If there are better approaches instead of using request.js I'm open to it. I can tell request.js is very popular, but also I'm very new to node.

thank you all very much

Comment: you want your post request in synchronous manner ?

Comment: @Sagar yes, in this case things are synchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format it just like you do for curl:

```
var formData = {
  oauth_token: '***',
  'track[asset_data]': fs.createReadStream('music.wav'),
  'track[title]': 'Track title',
  'track[sharing]': 'public'
}
```